# [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: next.js, next-auth

When i click on google login btn, it redirects to /api/auth/error.
I use next.js v14

My nextauth.js file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook"
export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId:
            process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    cookies: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // Set to true in production
        domain: "http://localhost:3000/pages/api/auth/callback/google", // Set your production domain here
    },
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

My file structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7twF.png)
My .env:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=Here is my id

GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=Here is my secret

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/pages/api/auth[...nextauth].js

NEXTAUTH_SECRET=ddssadasksmkmdkmkmo
```

I tried file structure /api/auth/[..nextauth]/route.js, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you config is incorrect. you can check  following config

```
            // authOption.ts
            
            import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
            import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
            import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
            
            export const authOptions = {
              secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
              session: {
                strategy: "jwt",
              },
            
              useSecureCookies: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
            
              providers: [
                GoogleProvider({
                  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
                  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
                  authorization: {
                    params: {
                      prompt: "consent",
                      access_type: "offline",
                      response_type: "code",
                    },
                  },
                }),
              ],
              callbacks: {
              },
            } satisfies NextAuthOptions;
    
    
  api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts - import AUTHOPTIONS HERE

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth/authOptions";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

AND In google developer console - APIs and Services > credentials

you need to add Authorised JavaScript origins and Authorised redirect URIs. appended images

[Authorised JavaScript origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocxw1.png)
[Authorised redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiAwM.png)